# Add the \in (is a member of the set) notation into qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a simple code as below. I would like to create the x-lable with the math notation "x \in [1,10]" to demonstrate that x is continuous and is a member of a particular interval/set. Is there anyway to set that?

```
cat("\014")
require(ggplot2)
n=10
x=seq(1,n,0.01)
y=x*x-2*x-30
x;y
m <- qplot(x, y, xlim=c(0,n),  xlab = "x in [1, 10]", ylab="", axis = FALSE)
m
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use an `expression`; see `?plotmath` for a list and examples

```
require(ggplot2)
n=10
x=seq(1,n,0.01)
y=x*x-2*x-30
qplot(x, y, xlim=c(0,n),  xlab = expression(x %in% '[1, 10]'), ylab="", axis = FALSE)
```

[image]